# Handling UIResponder for UITextView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiresponder

I am trying to handle `UIResponder` for an existing subclass of `UITextView` in SwiftUI. I have been able to use the Coordinator pattern to handle `UITextViewDelegate` but I'm having trouble with `UIResponder`.

In the past (with UIKit), what I would have done is use `NotificationCenter` to add an observer for `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` in a subclass of `UIViewController`.

In SwiftUI, I'm not sure where to put it. I've done a simple thing which is to re-use the Coordinator class in `makeUIView`, as in:

```
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(context.coordinator, selector: #selector(Coordinator.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: editorTextView)
```

But the `keyboardWillShow` method never gets called. Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using a Combine Publisher so you don't need to mess with selectors, but this should work either way. The observer/selector pattern is commented out in this example, but if you uncomment it both the observer and the publisher should respond when the keyboard appears.

```
    import Combine
    import SwiftUI
    import UIKit

    struct MyTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    // Pass in the binding to the string from the SwiftUI view
    var text: Binding<String>

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self.text = text
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.delegate = context.coordinator
        tf.text = context.coordinator.text.wrappedValue // Access the wrapped value in the binding
        return tf
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        //
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> MyTextViewDelegate {
        let delegate = MyTextViewDelegate(text: text)
        return delegate
    }

    class MyTextViewDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
//      let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        var text: Binding<String>

        // You can use a Combine Publisher rather than dealing with selectors
        var subscriber: AnyCancellable?

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            self.text = text
            super.init()
            subscriber = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification)
                .sink() { [weak self] note in
                    print(self?.text.wrappedValue ?? "nil")
                    print("Publisher called -> " + note.description)
            }
//            nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        }


//        @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
//            print("Selector called -> " + notification.description)
//        }

        // Value should update in SwiftUI when return key is pressed to show that the data flows
        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""
            print(textField.text!)
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the lifetime of `subscriber`? The issue would be that in the `sink` handler, I'd like to use `self.text` but Swift doesn't allow access to `self` when initializing the `subscriber` property.

Comment: The subscriber will be retained for as long as MyTextViewDelegate stays around, effectively working like an observer. Subscribers have a notion of 'completing' the subscription which effectively removes the subscriber but that wouldn't be relevant in this case. I've updated the answer above to declare subscriber as an Optional<AnyCancellable>, and then assign the subscriber to it in init() after super.init() so self is available. Is this helpful or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: One other question about this - is it necessary to implement `dismantleUIView` and `cancel()` all the `AnyCancellable` properties?

Comment: Nope you're good. `dismantleUIView`has a default implementation so you likely won't need to implement your own in most cases. `cancel()` would be relevant only if you want to explicitly end a subscription-in-progress. It will get cleaned up automatically when your view is deallocated.